Jsonb.fromJson does not deserialize the Set produced from the JSON string generated by Jsonb.toJson(objectWithSet)
I have a sample object (included below) that is intended to be used with JAXB, JSON-B and JPA. I have writen some unit tests to verify the output but the JSON-B is giving me a little fuss. When I deserialize the object that was just serialized the products do not match. Namely the Set is not getting deserialized even though it was serialized fine.
I started with JAXB and was able to get it to work as expected.
I had to create the Directory class to get the Set to handle properly and then created the XmlJavaTypeAdapter to handle Path.
Since it only seems to be going one way I tried to just create a JsonbDeserializer<Set<ArtifactDirectory>> but using new JsonbConfig().withDeserializers(new DirectorySetDeserializer()) did not seem to work. Infact it didn't even use the class at all.
The idea is to be able to use one object for JAXB, JSON and JPA over REST, which is proving to be much more complicated than I would have ever thought.
I added the unit tests to give me more confidence that
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response persistReview(Review review) {
    ...
}

was going to work as expected. (It of course does not)
Maven POM:
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.json.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.json.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
    <artifactId>yasson</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>

Directory Class (contained in Set):
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Directory {
    @XmlElement
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ArtifactDirectoryTranslator.class)
    private Path path;

    public Directory() {}
    
    public Directory(Path path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public Path getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(Path path) {
        this.path = path;
    }
}

JAXB/JSONB/Entity Class:
@XmlRootElement(name = "review")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Review {
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "artifact-directories")
    private final Set<Directory> directories = new HashSet<>();
    
    public Review addDirectory(Path dirPath) {
        directories.add(new Directory(dirPath));
        return this;
    }
    
    public Set<Directory> getDirectories() {
        return directories;
    }
    
    public void setDirectories(Set<Directory> directories) {
        // done this way for JPA/Hibernate
        this.directories.clear();
        this.directories.addAll(directories);
    }
}

Unit Test:
@Test
public void testJsonb() {
    Review uut_review = new Review();
    uut_review.addDirectory(Path.of("/some/path/1"));
    uut_review.addDirectory(Path.of("/some/path/2"));

    JsonbConfig config = new JsonbConfig().withFormatting(true);
    Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.newBuilder().withConfig(config).build();
    
    // totally fine: {"directories":[{"path": "/some/path/1"}, {"path": "/some/path/2"}]}
    String jsonResult = jsonb.toJson(uut_review);
    System.out.println(jsonResult);    

    // not so good: {"directories":[]}
    Review actualReivew = jsonb.fromJson(jsonResult, Review.class);
    String jsonResult2 = jsonb.toJson(actualDataReivew);
    System.out.println(jsonResult2);
}

Unit Test Ouput:
{
    "directories": [
        {
            "path": "/some/path/1"
        },
        {
            "path": "/some/path/2"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "directories": [
    ]
}


So as it turns out is was the "final" on the directories Set. When the directories set is NOT final JSON-B will work as expected.

I implemented the example from scratch again and this time accidentally forgot to make directories final and it magically worked. I have been able to confirm removing the final keyword results in the expected result. Good to know
